# Is $ \left\{\frac{\sin\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{x}{n}}\right\}$ uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

In order to calculate 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty n\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)[x(1+x^2)]^{-1}dx,
$$
I have the following question:

> Let $$
> f_n(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\frac{x}{n}},\quad x\in(0,\infty).
> $$
>   Is $\{f_n\}$ uniformly bounded?

It is not difficult the get a bound for every $f_n$ using 
$$
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin (y)}{y}=1. 
$$
How can I get a uniform bound?

More generally, how does one show that a sequence of functions is uniformly bounded?

Comment: Let $h(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ and note that $f_n(x) = h(x/n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel's comment, one only needs to show that 
$$
h(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}
$$ 
is bounded.